# How to make my code faster and easier?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

This is my .cs part code where I am calling `storeprocedure` in LINQ to SQL:

```
var rr_j_cat = db.allcategories().ToList();//its store procedure calling thousands of rows

if (rr_j_cat.Count() != 0)
 {
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();//making dynamic datatable
   dt.Columns.Add("sub_id");  //dynamic columns
   dt.Columns.Add("sibheadername");  //dynamic columns
   foreach (var it in rr_j_cat) // will rotate thousands time which makes process talking more time 
   {
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); // dyanamic rows
      var rr_sel_cat = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(it.sub_id)).ToList(); //another storeprocedure to check a count of data present in another data or table        
      int count = Convert.ToInt32(rr_sel_cat.First().Column1);
      if (count != 0)
       {
         dr["sub_id"] = it.sub_id;
         dr["sibheadername"] = it.sibheadername + " (" + count + ")"; // adding count besides subheader name which you can see in below image on dance 
         count =0;
        }
        else
        {
           dr["sub_id"] = it.sub_id;
            dr["sibheadername"] = it.sibheadername;
        }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
     dd_j_area.DataSource = dt; // binding with dropdownlist
     dd_j_area.DataTextField = "sibheadername";
     dd_j_area.DataValueField = "sub_id";
     dd_j_area.DataBind();
     dd_j_area.Items.Insert(0, "");
}
```

It's working fine, but taking more time.

It will show as

[image: here]

Comment: Can you not have one stored procedure return you the results rather than having to call two?

Comment: Have you thought about writing it in assembly?  Bad and overused joke... sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal performance issues are on the database side (or maybe you could do some kind of caching or pre-loading), but your code could be made much clearer and shorter (there should be also some minor performance improvements):

```
string[] columnNames = new[] { "sub_id", "sibheadername" };

var categories = db.allcategories().ToList(); 

if (categories.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(columnNames[0]);
dt.Columns.Add(columnNames[1]);

foreach (var category in categories)
{
    var selectedCategories = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(category.sub_id)).ToList();
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(selectedCategories.First().Column1);

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = category.sub_id;
    dr[1] = count != 0
                ? category.sibheadername + " (" + count + ")" // btw. this is FASTER (in this case) than a StringBuilder!
                : category.sibheadername;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

areaDropdown.DataSource = dt;
areaDropdown.DataTextField = columnNames[1];
areaDropdown.DataValueField = columnNames[0];
areaDropdown.DataBind();
areaDropdown.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

Comment: dr is missing..

Comment: You're right. Simply overseen it. Will edit the answer.

Comment: hey its working faster

Comment: Nice to hear! You're welcome.

Comment: As i am using storeprocedure is there any necessary of using precompiling??

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be using `StringBuilder`:

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder sibHeaderNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sibHeaderNameBuilder.Append(it.sibheadername);
        sibHeaderNameBuilder.Append("(");
        sibHeaderNameBuilder.Append(count);
        sibHeaderNameBuilder.Append(")");
        dr["sibheadername"] = sibHeaderNameBuilder.ToString();
```

Note that using the `stringBuilder.Append(int value)` method, you don't have to convert use the string representation of `count`.

Comment: its adding one more class of using System.Text; ....and on every loop it call this....i think it will make more load on page of name space and this code?????think so...

Comment: OK, but you should instantiate the stringBuilder object outside of your loop. Also instead of using string concatenation you can use String.Format(), which will be more faster.

Comment: Umhh, nope. Using StringBuilder is actually slower in this concrete case, because the compiler will optimize the statement `" (" + count + ")"`.

Comment: You are right Thomas about the StringBuilder, but I think StringBuilder is a little bit more efficient (in case of memory management) than using string concatenation.

Comment: Generally speaking yes. Actually a **lot** more efficient (I've seen cases where this was around 1000 times faster). The only case where direct concatenation is faster is the `"x" + <somevar> + "y"` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You asked two things,

1. Clearer code
2. Better performance

I'll try to cover both.

First of all it's unnecessary to convert `rr_j_cat` and `rr_sel_cat` to list again!
So `rr_j` and `rr_list` variables are both useless.

Second, instead of converting `rr_sel_cat.First().Column1` to string, which in your case will instantiate a string variable (`count`) over and over, convert it to and `int` or if it's already an `int` or a value type, use it instead and avoid unnecessary boxing which is a performance issue.

Third, instead of string concatenating in `dr["sibheadername"] = it.sibheadername + " (" + count + ")";`, use `StringBuilder` class which will be a good performance improvement in your case.

Comment: how to make use stringbuilder in this case?..please will u give some demo based on my question??

Comment: as you suggested other things are being changed....but string builder is good to use ?

Comment: Actually StringBuilder is more efficient in case of using memory, but the fastest way will be using string.Format().

Comment: Umhh, nope. First, the `ToList()` prevents the stored procedure from being executed more than once. Second, using StringBuilder is actually slower in this concrete case, because the compiler will optimize the statement `" (" + count + ")"`.